# Is there any way to access date of actionts in websites trough selenium python?

Tags: jquery, ajax, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to access the date of data such as date of comments. But HTML codes doesn't have such information. Could you help me how can I solve it by selenium python? The solution can be solved by j query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the date getting displayed on the web-page?

If it's something which can't be seen on the web-page, cannot be accessed by selenium also.